# What is the correct way of defining event in meteor application for shown event of modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, meteor

I have a jquery handler as following;

```
$('#input-output-match').on('shown', function () {
        console.log('inside on shown function ');
        instance.constructResultSets();
        instance.connectResultSets();
    });
```

I'm using **bootstrap 2.3.2** and meteor applicaton, so I want to write an event for the same purpose. This is my attempt so far:

```
Template.flowchart.events({
'shown #input-output-match':function(e){
    console.log('invoked!');
}
});
```

But it does not invoked, what is the correct way of doing it?

Comment: Because the event is of Bootstrap, the correct way _in this case_ is the first one

Comment: Thanks for reply, so Should'nt I convert it to meteor event? @Tushar

Comment: Meteor has only click, dblclick, focus, blur, change, mouseenter, mouseleave, mousedown, mouseup, keydown, keypress, keyup events. "Other DOM events are available as well, but for the events above, Meteor has taken some care to ensure that they work uniformly in all browsers." - http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/eventmaps

Comment: Would the template's onRendered() event work for you?